# Alternative formula for the Bernoulli pmf?

Tags: distributions, density-function, bernoulli-distribution, discrete-distributions

If I understand correctly, a Bernoulli pmf just needs to assign a probability $p$ if there is a success $(x=1)$, and $1-p$ otherwise $(x = 0)$. Rather than the usual formula, can't the following function also satisfy this condition and represent a the pmf of a Bernoulli RV?

$
f(x) = xp + (1-x)(1-p).
$

So if $f(x=1) = p, f(x=0) = 1-p.$

What would be wrong in formulating it this way?

Comment: Steve, could you tell why you think it is wrong?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this. In fact, you'll often see the log-likelihood of logistic regression (with binary outcomes) written as [the log of what you describe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy#Cross-entropy_loss_function_and_logistic_regression).

Comment: In fact you can go with $p^x(1-p) ^{1-x}.$ There is nothing wrong in writing like that.

Comment: The reason I am questioning it is just because it is not the usual derivation, rather the x and 1-x in  the exponents are what are typically used. So I guess I assumed the reason we dont see it the way I wrote it is because there is something I am missing - like it violates a property of probabilities or some sort.

Comment: The formulation in the comment by @User1865345 is far more useful for working with likelihoods.

Comment: I prefer 
$$f(x) = p  \sin\left( \frac{x\pi}{2} \right) + (1-p)  \cos\left( \frac{x\pi}{2} \right) $$

Comment: It is also important to state along with the formula that $x \in {0,1}$. The formula is a simplification of $$f(x)=\begin{cases} p & \text{if $x=1$} \\
                   1-p & \text{if $x=0$} 
      \end{cases}$$ and for that case the support is less ambiguous (actually, it can still be ambiguous, but it is conventional to leave out the 'else f(x) = 0 cases').

Comment: The trouble with writing $f(x) = xp + (1-x)(1-p)$ is that it makes it look like $f$ is a continuous function of the real numbers, with nonzero values for $x$ in the interval $(0,1)$. The density function of a Bernouilli variable needs to either not be defined, or be equal to 0, where $x$ is not $0$ or $1$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your alternative form is often written *braced form* as
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases} p & \text{if $x=1$} \\
                   1-p & \text{if $x=0$}
      \end{cases} $$
and there is nothing wrong with that. It might be useful, for instance, for programming and for elementary exposition.

But if you want to do any form of algebra or calculus, it is inconvenient, so the other form is preferred. But both forms are equally valid, it is only a pragmatic question of what works best for whatever you are doing with it.

Comment: And $f(x)=0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 9):

There's nothing wrong with it as it evaluates the values, it should evaluate. The usual formulation however uses powers so it becomes a case of binomial distribution with $n=1$ sample size. Recall that the probability mass function of [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) is

$$
{n \choose x} \,p^x (1-p)^{n-x}
$$

Where we have $n$ [independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)) Bernoulli distributed with $x$ successes observed, hence $p^x$, and $n-x$ failures. The ${n \choose x}$ corrects for the fact that we want to account for the successes and failures appearing in any possible [combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination). With $n=1$ and $x \in \{0,1\}$ it reduces to Bernoulli distribution formulated with the powers

$$
\,p^x (1-p)^{1-x}
$$

Answer (score 2):

This is fine, assuming that the domain of $f$ is $\{0,1\}$.
This is also true of the formulations in the other answers.
A different formulation involving the [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) is
\begin{align*}
f(x) = (1-p)[x=0]+p[x=1].\tag{1}
\end{align*}
One defines
\begin{align*}
[P] &= \begin{cases}
1, & \textrm{if $P$ is true}, \\
0, & \textrm{else.}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
The Iverson bracket has many interesting algebraic properties that capture the logic of the statement $P$. One interesting difference with formulation (1) is that the domain of $f$ can be thought of as all of $\mathbb{Z}$ (or indeed all of $\mathbb{R}$).
This allows one to be loose with notation in a way that is totally rigorous.
For example, the expected value of $g(x)$ is
$$\sum_x g(x)f(x),$$
where the sum is typically understood to be over all of $\mathbb{Z}$, with the result
$$g(0)(1-p) + g(1)p.$$